# Bash transforms my ping command after a successful "until loop"

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script that continuously attempts to ping a domain until it becomes reachable. My aim is to exit with a 0 on success and a 1 on fail after all retry attempts have exceeded.

Here's the script:

```
#! /bin/bash

attempt_counter=0
max_attempts=20

until $(ping -c 1 "$1"); do
    if [ ${attempt_counter} -eq ${max_attempts} ];then
      echo "Max attempts reached"
      exit 1
    fi

    printf '.'
    attempt_counter=$(($attempt_counter+1))
    sleep 5
done
```

However, as soon as the ping is a success, the exit *doesn't occur* and a weird error is displayed instead:

```
/var/opt/openvpn/wait-on-ping.sh some.domain
ping: unknown host some.domain
.
ping: unknown host some.domain
.
######## AS THIS POINT DOMAIN IS REACHABLE ########
/var/opt/wait-on-ping.sh: line 6: PING: command not found
```

Is my **until** condition written incorrectly since my ping exits with 0 on success?

Comment: What's with the `$( )`?

Comment: That is to say, your code should just be `until ping -c 1 "$1"; do`, maybe with a `>/dev/null` or such if you don't want `ping`'s output going to the TTY.

Comment: ...btw, I would also suggest `if (( attempt_counter == max_attempts )); then` -- if you've got a bash shebang, might as well take advantage of it and use C-style math. Similarly, `(( ++attempt_counter ))` is a shorter increment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...anything...)` expands to the **output from** the command `...anything...`.

Thus, if `ping` emits a string on its stdout that starts with the word `PING`, then `$(ping)` will try to run `PING` -- that output -- as a command. (By contrast, `var=$(ping)` would assign that output to a variable, or `[ -n "$(ping)" ]` would test whether that output was empty or not).

---

Take out the command substitution if you don't want this behavior: Your code should just be:

```
 until ping -c 1 "$1"
```

...with no `$( )` involved.

Comment: thanks it works. Wasn't familiar with the expand. Saw that somehow and used it in a wrong way.